# Why is the comparator method giving positive value first then negative?

Tags: java

The comparator method is giving positive value first then negative:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class FindMinArrowShots {
    public static int findMinArrowShots(int[][] points) {
        if(points.length<=1){
            return points.length;
        }
        Arrays.sort(points,(a,b)->a[0]-b[0]);
        for(int i=0;i<points.length;i++){
            System.out.println(points[i][0] + "," + points[i][1]+" ");

        }
        int compare=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int shots=1;
        for (int i=0;i<points.length;i++) {
            if(points[i][0]>compare){
                compare=points[i][1];
                shots++;
            }
            compare=Math.min(compare,points[i][1]);
        }
        return shots;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(findMinArrowShots(new int[][]{{-2147483646,-2147483645 } ,{ 2147483646,2147483647 } }));
    }
}
```

e.g. the input
`(new int[][]{{-2147483646,-2147483645}, {2147483646, 2147483647}})`

is giving the output
`{{ 2147483646,2147483647 },{-2147483646,-2147483645 }}`

Also the input
`(new int[][]{{-2147483646,-2147483645 }, {2147483646, 2147483647}})`

is giving the output
`{{ 2147483646,2147483647}, {-2147483646,-2147483645 }}`
instead of
`{{-2147483646,-2147483645}, { 2147483646, 2147483647 }}`

Comment: This is very likely because of integer over- / underflow. You use values that are very close to integers minimum value, so when you compare them by simply using the `-` operator you will get wrong results.

Comment: Try to change`(a,b)->a[0]-b[0]` to  `(a,b)->Integer.compare(a[0], b[0])`  and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS is right. `-2147483646 - 2147483646` overflows to `4`, which means that the sorting thinks that `2147483646` is __larger__ than `2147483646`.